# Should I quit my job for before signing contract with another employer?

Tags: work-environment, work-experience, employer-relations, employees, employment

I'm a senior developer in an advertising company, which due to current economic situations I faced various problems with them.

- First : We have a delayed monthly payment which causes many problems.
- Second: They have set of punishment rules for employees, for example starting the working hours is 8 and if I go to work after 8:45 they record that as an absents and will double it if I don't go to work, meaning they will cut a day of my monthly payment and will cut another extra day for punishment if I don't go to work that day.
- Third: There is no promising project or future for the company the way I see and I won't see any progress until a great change happens to the management.

I have interviewed another company which sounds promising and they have more benefits for me as a developer, but I don't know for sure that it won't be like the current company after a while.

They told me: "you have to quit from the current position (which is a CTO) first,  then we will sign a contract with you, otherwise there wouldn't be any co-operation".

FYI: The current company won't let me leave easily and there would be a fight between us, and I probably should go to law institute for that, and new employer know that.

That's the situation I'm in right now. What should I do in this kind of situation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102023/discussion-on-question-by-mohammad-hosseini-should-i-quit-my-job-for-before-sign).

Comment: see also https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4098/should-i-resign-from-my-current-job-before-getting-acceptance-letter-from-the-ne

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> *Should I quit my job for before signing contract with another employer?*

### NO.

**Rule of Thumb: Do not quit unless you have a written and signed agreement for the next employment.**

Any verbal discussion / assurance is not good enough to be held as true. There is no legal credibility of any verbal commitment made by any individual (whether in a personal capacity of on behalf of an organization) - that can be changed / denied at any point of time unilaterally. Do not rely on this.

Answer (score 25):

If they expect you to quit your job before making you a written offer, it's utter nonsense. You probably don't want to have anything to do with them. Run and keep looking for other opportunities.

Comment: And possibly leave a _nice_ Glassdoor review about the experience.

Comment: Exactly. I've never heard of this. It sounds like they want to make you desperate for a job so will accept a lower salary or worse working conditions. Major red flag.

Answer (score 2):

I’d want to know in which country this is happening. In the western world, expecting me to quit before an offer is made is utterly ridiculous. There are two possible explanations: Either the company is run by someone who is totally inexperienced, or it is run by someone who wants to put you into a very uncomfortable position in order to exploit you. You would never, ever accept this. You may decide if you want to tell them your reasons why you find this unacceptable and see if they drop this requirement, or if you just don’t trust them.

Apart from that, anywhere in the western world your company has to pay for the time you worked, and in many places you have the right to sue them for payment long after you leave the company.

Comment: I'm living in the middle east, And as I said first year and a half everything was good, after some economic problems all thing went south, anyway I have used local law to force them to pay my delayed payments and it's over now.

Comment: Good to hear that. Wish you good luck to find a good job.

Comment: Thanks, I already working as a freelancer.